# Angular 2 inline template : Variable undefined in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Angular 2 app have been encountering an error saying "Error: Error in ./SampleComponent class SampleComponent - inline template caused by: Variable undefined in strict mode".
But I get this error only in IE 10>.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name" [nameFormatter]="selected">
```

Here the "`selected`" value passed to the attribute directive `nameFormatter` is a variable that is initialized in the component.If I try removing the `selected` variable with some static values this seems to work fine.Assigning it with the `selected` variable causes this issue.

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
   public selected : string;

    someFunction(){
         this.selected="some value" //The value changes depending on some conditions
    }
}
```

Is there something to do with polyfills.I tried adding the below polyfills to index.html with no luck.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Could someone please guide me on this.

Comment: And did you try just initializing the variable? `public selected : string = "";`

Comment: tanx @Arg0n.I tried adding those.But the effect seems to be same

Comment: You'll have to post more code. Can we see the html for this component? in general the error `Variable undefined in strict mode` happens in `strict mode` (which TS uses by default) due to not using var declaration so this would generate the error `somevar = 5` while this would be fine `var somevar = 5`

Comment: @AhmedMusallam.Tanx for the reply.How come it then works in all other browser except IE ?

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `somefunction` does not refer to `NameComponent`, it's in a different closure.

If your goal is to call the function from the view (`html`) then do this:

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
   public selected : string;

   someFunction(){
     this.selected="some value" //The value changes depending on some conditions
   }
}
```

Comment: Typo.my bad.Edited the question.The function is with the `NameComponent`.